# Do deferred tasks affect the performance of non deferred backend operations in the application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been developing an application in google appengine and trying to optimize some of my endpoints. I have several deferred task running in which in some cases will in parallel with other non deferred operations and I want to know if I will consider deferred tasks are factors for my optimization?

Comment: Please, do not vote to close a question if you don't understand it.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I think this question has reasonable scope.

Comment: @Kekito, agree -- though it would be better if the OP showed an app.yaml sample to clarify their terms.

Answer (score 1):

Deferred tasks will call the same instances that run your app, unless you specify a different target for these tasks. So they will share resources with the other tasks.

Typically, this is a desired behavior as it leads to a fuller utilization of existing instances instead of creating more under-utilized instances. App Engine will spin more instances, if necessary. Obviously, there are other factors to consider - start up time of your instances, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that App Engine will spin more instances for scaling. Startup time of dynamic instances may cause slow down on the performance and I am now considering auto scaling and setup a number resident instances.

Comment: You can also "warm up" a new instance before your deferred task is scheduled to run, to prevent a slow down for regular users. Also, you can spread your tasks over a longer period of time, if you are concerned about their impact, by limiting the number of tasks that run in parallel (in your queue definition).